# How do I number my images as examples?

Tags: floats, linguistics, syntax, examples

I am trying to insert Syntax trees into a paper I am writing, but I am not sure how to number them. My trees are .png files, and I am inserting them into the document using `\begin{figure}` however, when I try to use `\begin{exe}` to number the example, the number shows up at the bottom left corner of the image and not the top left corner where I would like it. I would rather number my trees with `\begin{exe}` than give them a caption under the figure environment. I get the same result if I just insert the image using \insertgraphics without the figure environment. Any ideas how I can do this?

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
%

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./images/}}


\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[citestyle=chicago-authordate]{biblatex} %Imports biblatex package
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib} %Import the bibliography file

\usepackage{ccg-latex}
%\usepackage{mathptmx} % this font is for demo. CM fonts look ugly.

\usepackage{gb4e}
%\usepackage{lscape}
%\usepackage[linguistics]{forest} %to draw syntax trees 
%\usepackage{ulem}
%\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}
%
\title{German Verb Particles Constructions in CCG}%\thanks{}}

\author{Name}

\authorrunning{Name}

\institute{University Name}

\email{example@example.edu}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

Abstract Text

\keywords{word1 \and word2 \and word3}

\end{Abstract}


\section{Introduction}
 Here is some text...

\beging{exe}
\ex
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{images/myimage.png
    %\caption{Caption}
    %\label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
\end{exe}



\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This is the resulting image in my PDF, however, I'd like the number to go at the top left.

[image]

I forget why exactly I am inserting the tree as an image, but if I rememeber correctly, I think the document wouldn't compile when I tried using the forest package for it, so I decided png files would be easier.

Comment: I couldn't find exe in any of the packages I have downloaded, which leaves llncs, ccg-latex and gb4e.  BTW, why are you using a figure when you don't have a caption?

Comment: In addition to what @JohnKormylo said (don't use the `figure` environment), why are you including trees as images in the first place? It's a `forest` tree, so just use `\begin{exe}\ex\label{mytree}\begin{forest} ...\end{forest}\end{exe}`

Comment: And if you're including graphics like trees anyway, you should include them in PDF form rather than `.png`.

Comment: if I remember correctly, I decided to insert my trees as images because i couldn't get forest to work with the llncs template that I am working with. I forget exactly what happened but the file wouldn't compile. @John Kormylo exe is part of gb4e if i remember correctly. I'm pretty new to LaTeX so I am just trying to figure it out as I go. why should I insert them as PDfs instead of PNGs?

Comment: PDFs (vector) have higher resolution than PNGs (raster).  The purpose of a float (figure and table) is to move it to a better location, usually the top of a page.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're wrapping the imagine in the `figure` environment. There's a tendency for people to think that all pictures need to go inside a `figure` or all tables need to go inside a `table`, but these environments are all about the placement on the page. Take out the `figure` environment and it should be closer to what you want.

Comment: I did take it out, but it didn't help, the example number would still appear where I showed it in the post. Someone suggested I force a line break in before I insert the figure and that seemed to work.